# How do i get a unique value from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I can't figure out how to get one value form SQL to show it. I make the search and then want to show it in dr2[3]

```
       foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            {
                //Buscar ventas de esa semana
                con.SqlQuery("Select PPstadmax from PPminmax where ppwochennr = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and PPartikelnr ='" + dr[0] + "'");

                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

                dt2.Columns.Add("art", typeof(int));
                dt2.Columns.Add("Beschreibung", typeof(string));
                dt2.Columns.Add("Flasche", typeof(string));
                dt2.Columns.Add("Hist.Verkauft", typeof(int));
                dt2.Columns.Add("Bestand", typeof(int));
                dt2.Columns.Add("Produktion", typeof(int));
                dt2.Columns.Add("Nächste Prod", typeof(int));
                DataRow dr2 = dt2.NewRow();

                dr2[0] = dr[0]; 
                dr2[1] = dr[1]; 
                dr2[2] = dr[3]; 
   here  >>>>   dr2[3] = I want the value i found here
                dr[4] = 0; 
                dr[5] = 0; 
                dr[6] = 0; 
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query will return a value or values. You may want to use something like a LIMIT (MySQL) on the end of your query to prevent multiple items from potentially being returned.

You will then need to store your returned value as a variable before setting

```
dr2[3] = variable
```